# checkbox within radiobutton in cq dialog

Tags: widget, aem

How to implement checkbox within radio button in cq dialog? I have the following code in my cq dialog:

```
<<eyecatcher
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            title="title"
            name="title"
            type="radio"
            xtype="selection">
        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <yes jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="yes"
                value="yes" >
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <new jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="new"
                        name="./new"
                        type="checkbox"
                        xtype="selection">
                    </new>
                    <offer jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Offer"
                        name="./offer"
                        type="checkbox"
                        xtype="selection">
                    </offer>
                </items>
            </yes>
            <no jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="no"
                value="no"/>
        </options>
    </eyecatcher>
```

When I douple click on the dialog, I can see only the radio button. what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. You can't nest these widgets. Please explain a bit what you are trying to achieve and maybe someone can show you a way to implement it.

Comment: Might be you should look over the listener concepts inside CQ5. Just create two radio button, and on alternate selection, make your checkbox hide or show.